# Node.js Express: echo the POST body regardless of its Content-Type?

Tags: node.js, post, express

I want to write the simplest POST-method handler in Node.JS+Express, so I have:

```
app.post('/someVerb', function(request, response){
  response.send("OK!");
});
```

Now, I want to make the method respond echoing the information that was sent in the POST body.

I've tried:

```
app.post('/someVerb', function(request, response){
  response.send("OK!: " + request.body);
});
```

But it doesn't work. I've started reading about capturing the POST data, and many stackoverflow posts and tutorials start talking about the BodyParser and the ContentType.

However, I don't want to deal with content-type yet. I want to simply echo, regardless of the content-type, so I don't want to parse the body either.

For example, I want a request made with `curl --data "foobarbaz" https://someapp.com/someVerb` simply return `foobarbaz`.

Answer (score 0):

[raw-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-body) will allow you to get any the full as a Buffer. To echo it back as a string, you'll need to deal with encodings but the example in the raw-body README shows one approach. You could decide to echo binary data back as hex encoded or base64 perhaps.

Comment: but how to use raw-body with express?

Comment: le shit, well, somehow I missed it because I didn't see an app.get() or app.post() call, why app.use?

Comment: Well HTTP GET requests generally do not have bodies thus body-related middlewares have no function for a GET request. `app.use` covers all methods both with and without bodies so it's convenient for example purposes.

Comment: ok so app.use works with any method, that's fine by me, but how to specify the `someVerb`?

Comment: I mean, in the example it's not there, is it smart enough to work with or without it?

Comment: If you just wanted this for a specific path you would use `app.post('/someVerb', ...)`